# integrating KENDOUI toolbar with grid toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, toolbar

i want to integrate KENDOUI toolbar [toolbar](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/index) with basic CRUD toolbar operation of KENDOUI grid [grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline).
I want to have button 'create' in my basic toolbar (first link) that adds new line in my grid(second link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can *combine* the Kendo ToolBar widget with the built-in grid toolbar but you can completely define the grid's toolbar using a template which can be a Kendo ToolBar that you have complete control over.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/OJAbI

In this example I have taken the 2 demos you linked to and added the ToolBar from the ToolBar demo and added it as the toolbar for the Grid using the toolbar.template configuration:

```
toolbar: [
{
    template: '<div id="toolbar"></div>'
}],
```

Then, the "toolbar" element gets converted to a full ToolBar with

```
$("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({...});
```

in which I have added a "Add new record" button and the click handler of the ToolBar is

```
click: function(e) {
    $("#grid").getKendoGrid().addRow();
}
```

Comment: thanks you dude! can you help me to edit/save line with the same way?