# How can I replace the kendoGrid toolbar with a kendoToolbar?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm ultimately trying to resize custom template controls that I've created in the `KendoGrid toolbar`. Right now they span the entire length of the toolbar and I'd like a way to resize them or collapse them into dropdown groups when the window is resized.

In the `kendoToolbar API`, anyone can use an overflow template to reorganize the toolbar, but I don't see anything in the Grid toolbar that does the same.

Any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo grid toolbar doesn't seem to offer as much flexibility as the actual toolbar widget. If you're confident that you can achieve what you need with the overflow template, the simplest solution would probably be to create a separate Toolbar yourself, setup the way you want. I've taken this approach a few times - with a little bit of CSS restyling, you can make the toolbar look identical to the one hosted by the grid and it should resize with it as well.

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="whiteBlock">
  <div id="my-grid-toolbar" style="border-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0.2em;"></div>
  <div id="my-grid"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also *never* use the built-in Grid ToolBar and always define the Grid's ToolBar using a template that contains a full Kendo ToolBar.  Link to similar question and my answer with working example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38123628/4825632

Comment: Would this be able to handle the grid actions such as Create?

Comment: Take a look at the post @TheDreadPirateStephen linked ... once you have a reference to the grid widget, you can drive most of it's functionality from the outside. In this case, it's the addRow() you would want.